# Put value straight into input textbox form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm grabbing a the last transaction value from https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/ticker/global/CAD/ and want to update it into an input textbox, but no matter what I try it won't show up.

here's a fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/h9w5tj8m/2/

```
var xbtc = new XMLHttpRequest();
xbtc.open('GET', 'https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/ticker/global/CAD/', true);
xbtc.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xbtc.readyState == 4) {
    var ticker = JSON.parse(xbtc.responseText);
    price = ticker.last;
    document.getElementById('btc').innerHTML = price;
    document.getElementById('cad').innerHTML = price;
  }
};
xbtc.send();
```

Comment: use `document.getElementById('cad').value = price;` instead

Comment: Solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[*updated fiddle*](https://jsfiddle.net/h9w5tj8m/3/)**

use

`document.getElementById('cad').value`

instead of

`document.getElementById('cad').innerHTML`

Simply understand with user interacted element `input,select,textarea` all are call with `value` for get the data from the elements.

All Other element's are call with `innerHTML` for get the data from the element

**[also refer different between `.value` and `.innerHTML`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31225901/difference-between-innerhtml-and-value-in-js)**

```
var xbtc = new XMLHttpRequest();
xbtc.open('GET', 'https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/ticker/global/CAD/', true);
xbtc.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xbtc.readyState == 4) {
    var ticker = JSON.parse(xbtc.responseText);
    price = ticker.last;
    document.getElementById('btc').innerHTML = price;
    document.getElementById('cad').value = price;
  }
};
xbtc.send();
```

Comment: Got it, thanks! can you explain why it won't work with innerHTML?

Answer (score 0):

There is no input type of "textbox". You need to change it to "text" or use a `<textarea></textarea>`. You can set the value of text input with `.value` and a textarea with `.innerHTML` or `.value`.

This fiddle works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/h9w5tj8m/4/

Answer (score 0):

using value attribute will place the value u retrieved into a particular textbox having a specific id .For Example :

```
 <input type ="textbox "  id="a">
    </input>
     <script>
 document.getElmentById("a").value=x;
 </script>
  //x is the variable where the retrieved data is stored.
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 document.getElementById('cad').value = price;
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [answer]. You should provide some information why your code solves the problem.
Code-only answers aren't useful for the community.