# Save data using javascript on Otree

Tags: javascript, html, otree

I am trying to save the timestamp from a click in a database on Otree. I tried using differents codes.

The first one is this

```
function myFunction() {
    var n = Date.now();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}

document.getElementById('n').value;
```

I put the next code in the html:

```
 <p style="text-align: center;"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-large" onclick="myFunction()"  name="offer_accepted" value="True">&nbsp;A</button> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <button class="btn btn-primary btn-large"  onclick="myFunction()" name="offer_accepted" value="False">B</button></p>
```

The next one is this:

```
function record_current_time(){
   var current_time = new Date();
   current_time = current_time.getTime()
   document.getElementById("id_currentTime").setAttribute("value", current_time)
}

window.onload = record_current_time;
```

And put the next code in my html:

```
  <input type="hidden" name="currentTime" id="id_currentTime"/>
```

In both cases I don't get anything in my database.

Can someone help me

Comment: Have you defined the corresponding field in your model? Have you tried generating the hidden input via the page template (i.e. `{% formfield player.currentTime %}`) rather than hard-coding it? How is the form submitted?

Answer (score 1):

Your first code doesn't work for two reasons:

- You are using an ID that doesn't exist: "demo"
- If you substitute .innerHTML with .value your code will work. See the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31225901/difference-between-innerhtml-and-value-in-js).

Regarding the second try, this command will work:

```
window.onload = function() {
    record_current_time();
}
```

Another possibility that works with the script at the top of the page is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        function record_current_time(){
           var current_time = new Date();
           current_time = current_time.getTime();
           document.getElementById('id_currentTime').value = current_time;
        }

        record_current_time();
});
```

However, you could also just put the script to the bottom of the page. Then all elements will be loaded when you execute the scripts.