# How to use it for many inputs with the same tag

Tags: javascript

I need this replacer to use it for many inputs with one selector. Now I use different selectors and same code with just selectors differ

```js
var en = "qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;'zxcvbnm,./`QWERTYUIOP{}ASDFGHJKL:\"ZXCVBNM<>?~&";
var ru = "йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбю.ёЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ,Ё?";
var alphabet = {};

for (var i = 0; i < en.length; i++) {
  alphabet[en[i]] = ru[i];
}

var InputReciever = document.getElementById("InputReciever");
InputReciever.addEventListener("input", function() {
  InputReciever.innerHTML = toRussianStr(this.value);
});

function toRussianStr(str) {
  return str.replace(/\S/g, function(match) {
    return alphabet[match] || match;
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="form__option">
  <input placeholder="Город получателя" id="InputReciever" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='Город получателя'" onkeydown="InputReciever.value=toRussianStr(InputReciever.value)" onchange="InputReciever.value=toRussianStr(InputReciever.value)"
    type="text" class="InputReciever field" autocomplete="off" />
</div>
```

Comment: What's the problem exactly? This code seems to be working, although the last letter remains latin. Use `onkeyup` instead of `onkeydown`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass `this` to the listener, and I would use `input` or `keyup` rather than `keydown`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.InputReciever')
```

```js
const toAlphabetMap = (from, to) => from.split('').reduce((acc, ch, i) =>
  ({ ...acc, [ch]: to.charAt(i) }), {});

const en = "qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;'zxcvbnm,./`QWERTYUIOP{}ASDFGHJKL:\"ZXCVBNM<>?~&";
const ru = "йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбю.ёЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ,Ё?";
const alphabet = toAlphabetMap(en, ru);

const toRussianStr = str => str.replace(/\S/g, match => alphabet[match] || match);

const handleInput = input => {
  console.log(input);
  input.value = toRussianStr(input.value)
};
```

```html
<div class="form__option">
  <input
    type="text"
    class="InputReciever field"
    placeholder="Город получателя"
    onfocus="this.placeholder=''"
    onblur="this.placeholder='Город получателя'"
    oninput="handleInput(this)"
    onchange="handleInput(this)"
    autocomplete="off" />
  <input
    type="text"
    class="InputReciever field"
    placeholder="Город получателя"
    onfocus="this.placeholder=''"
    onblur="this.placeholder='Город получателя'"
    oninput="handleInput(this)"
    onchange="handleInput(this)"
    autocomplete="off" />
</div>
```

Comment: I would use `oninput` rather than `onkeyup`.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use `document.getElementById`. Use `document.getElementsByTagName('input')`

Comment: You should include code where there is a `forEach` iterator since `getElementsByTagName` returns an array.

Comment: How is changing the selectors relevant to the question? If I understood correctly, the code works, the problem is that the last character is latin.

Comment: I think that we see a different problem. So I finally confused about the problem)

Answer (score 0):

Change the code inside the `input` event listener from `input.innerHTML` to `input.value`.
[Here's an answer explaining the differences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31225963/13331155).

Eg.

```js
var en = "qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;'zxcvbnm,./`QWERTYUIOP{}ASDFGHJKL:\"ZXCVBNM<>?~&";
var ru = "йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбю.ёЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ,Ё?";
var alphabet = {};

for (var i = 0; i < en.length; i++) {
  alphabet[en[i]] = ru[i];
}

var input = document.querySelector("input");
input.addEventListener("input", function() {
  input.value = toRussianStr(input.value);
});

function toRussianStr(str) {
  return str.replace(/\S/g, function(match) {
    return alphabet[match] || match;
  });
}
```

```html
<input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Город получателя" 
 autocomplete="off"/>
```